# TFS continuous integration Basic Setup

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

This is a very basic question. I never used CI before. so please help me understand.

I have a MVC project (c#.net), which i am checking into TFS online. This part works for me.

Now I seen companies, where when they check in, it creates a BUILD for them. This part I do not understand.

in my MVC project, All I want to do is...publish it to my host, so why do I want to create a build?

Why is build necessary? what does the build contains? its  a MVC project, so a build means a build of my MVC project (Same as I see under my "Release" folder")?

Can a CI publish the project to my host as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of using a build server is to have your software constructed on a system other than your own. You might have local binaries that allow the build to succeed on your local system, but if the remote system doesn't have those same binaries, it will fail. A build ensures you've encapsulated your entire solution that can, in turn, be deployed elsewhere.

The Continuous Integration build is basically a validation build. You could potentially add post-build steps to deploy to an environment, but often a separate build is constructed for deployments to various environments. You probably don't want to re-deploy with each validation build - that tends to be overkill.

Comment: so if i understand it correctly. BUILD server will DROP the build content to a "Location", which would look same as the "Release" folder within my project?after it creates a build I can deploy it to production?

Comment: In VSTS (aka TFS online) there are both Build and Release to avoid mixing build (generate some deploy-able package) and deploy (deploy the above package to some environment).

Comment: Khan, your understanding is exactly correct. Giulio, you are also correct, but you can also add a deployment step to a Build in VSTS by using a Deploy task. There are a number of these available in the Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your source code into binaries, exactly the same as what happens when you press "Build" in Visual Studio or debug your application.

Once you have binaries, *then* you can deploy them. Whether you deploy them to a test environment directly from your CI build or use a deployment pipeline (defined in the *Release* area) depends on numerous factors too complex to get into here.

Answer (score 0):

There are Gated Check-in and Continuous Integration (CI).

Regarding Gated Check-in, it is used to make sure the solution/project have no compile problem.

For example, there are some developers collaborate for a project, if there is the issue in your code (build failed in local), but you still check in changes to server, then others get the latest changes, which may affect others to do their work.

Regarding CI build, the main arm is to prevent integration problem. 
You may refer to this article to get more information about [Continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Regarding publish/deploy project to server, it better to create a new build definition instead of deploying project once there is changes checked in.